# RecyclerView swipeToDismiss Only partial row to be swiped with delete button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to do something like the below

[image]

where the recyclerView row should be swiped (Only partially) and show delete button at the right of the row.

I have searched for the example. Everything has full swipe like gmail app swipe to dismiss shows archive. But I want something like the attached image where the row can be swiped only partly and the rest of the row should have custom view containing delete button.

Can someone give me an example?

Thanks.

Comment: You can refer this link :https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview Swipe to delete works fine with this

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid I dont want the full swipe.. Can you see from the image attached. Its the restricted swipe leaving only 1/4th of the space at the end with custom view on it. The example swipes the entire row. Thanks

Comment: Yeah..it has an example for show button on swipe...where you can replace button with your layout....see screenshot in on google play for this sample

Comment: @user5001783 You can use AndroidSwipeLayout library. https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by adding below code in onChildDraw()

```
if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {

                    viewHolder?.itemView?.translationX = dX / 5
                    val p = Paint()
                    p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D32F2F"));
                    val background = RectF(viewHolder?.itemView?.getRight()?.toFloat()?.plus(dX/5) ?: 0.0f, viewHolder?.itemView?.getTop()?.toFloat() ?: 0.0f, viewHolder?.itemView?.getRight()?.toFloat() ?: 0.0f, viewHolder?.itemView?.getBottom()?.toFloat() ?: 0.0f);
                    c?.drawRect(background,p);
                    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources,R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp)
                    val background_dest = RectF(viewHolder?.itemView?.getRight()?.toFloat()?.plus(dX/5) ?: 0.0f, viewHolder?.itemView?.getTop()?.toFloat()?.div(2) ?: 0.0f, viewHolder?.itemView?.getRight()?.toFloat() ?: 0.0f, viewHolder?.itemView?.getBottom()?.toFloat() ?: 0.0f);
                    c?.drawBitmap(bitmap,null,background_dest,p)

                } else {
                    super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        @Override
        public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                                int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

            if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {

                View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;                    
                if(dX < 0) {
                    itemView.setTranslationX(dX / 5);
                    p.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.cherryRed));
                    RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() + dX, (float) itemView.getTop(), (float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());
                    c.drawRect(background, p);
                    //draw text or icon as you want
                }
            } else {
                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please explain your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
private const val buttonWidth = 300f
private var newDx = 0f

private fun stopSwipeInXDistance(
        c: Canvas,
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        dX: Float,
        dY: Float,
        actionState: Int,
        isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
    ) {
        newDx = dX //Important. We use this one in super, instead of regular dX
        val sign = sign(newDx)
        val limit = buttonWidth * sign

            when (sign) {
                -1f -> { //Swipe to left. button is on right side
                    if (newDx <= limit) {
                        newDx = limit
                    }
                }
                0f, 1f -> {
                    if (newDx >= limit) {
                        newDx = limit
                    }
                }
            }

        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, newDx, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
    }
```

And use it in `onChildDraw` instead of:

```kotlin
super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
```